# Linux patching ORacle Java SE 7

Tags: linux, java

So one of our servers was reported as vulnerable becuase it is running an EOL Oracle Java SE Version ( Oracle Java SE/JRE/JDK J7 / 1.7 ).

[Oracle Java SE Product Releases](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html)

[image]
The vulnerbaility scanner reported also many CVE's like the one address in [Oracle Critical Patch Update Advisory - October 2016](https://www.oracle.com/security-alerts/cpuoct2016.html)

[image]
My question is, how do I even install them ? I'm aware then Oracle indtroduced a paid subscription model that includes patches but they did it starting from Oracle Java SE 8.

PS. I know that the version is EOL but would an upgrade to a higher version also require the paid subscription to get ANY patches ?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the latest JDK, which is free. That also includes the free Java SE version. Just make sure to run the latest default-jre and check for any older versions and remove them. More info here may be helpful: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk-faqs.html